# Can't access the Kubernetes apiserver from within a pod

Tags: kubernetes

I read in the [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#accessing-the-api-from-a-pod)  that from within a pod you can access the Kubernetes apiserver with the `kubernetes.default.svc` DNS name. This name does resolve to an IP address, however, it seems that there's no response from this service endpoint.

```
// from within a container in a pod

# nslookup kubernetes.default.svc
nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolve

Name:      kubernetes.default.svc
Address 1: 10.96.0.1 kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
/ # ping 10.96.0.1
PING 10.96.0.1 (10.96.0.1): 56 data bytes
^C
--- 10.96.0.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

No response from the apiserver. Someone?

Comment: The IP that resolves is a kubernetes service IP, it will not respond to pings.
Does it respond to HTTPS requests to the API server port (443 or 6443 usually)?

Answer (score 1):

In kubernetes a Service exists of a IP **and port** pair (or multiple). It does not represent anything. The IP is just virtual and not assigned to a network interface. This is the reason, why you can't ping a service (pings do not get sent to a specific port).

Using curl/nc/telnet to access/connect to the API server via its service name & port will work.

e.g.:

```
$ curl -k https://kubernetes.default.svc:443
{
  "kind": "APIVersions",
  "versions": [
    "v1"
  ],
  "serverAddressByClientCIDRs": [
    {
      "clientCIDR": "0.0.0.0/0",
      "serverAddress": "10.0.1.149:443"
    }
  ]
}
```